# Meson, add build options to CMake subproject

Tags: cmake, meson-build

Basically I have a cmake subproject as part of my meson.build, I would like to be able to add `-DSOMEDEF=4` to the build of that subproject.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use [yield](https://mesonbuild.com/Build-options.html#yielding-to-superproject-option) in the `meson.options` file.

Add the option in your top project:

```
option('somedef',
    type : 'combo',
    choices : [
      '1',
      '2',
      '4'
      ],
    description : 'Some def')
```

Add the same option in your subproject, but with the `yield` set to `true`:

```
option('somedef',
    type : 'combo',
    choices : [
      '1',
      '2',
      '4'
      ],
    yield : true,
    description : 'Some def')
```

This way the option will be taken from the top project.

In your `meson.build` add something like (top project):

```
somedef = get_option('somedef')
```

and in the subproject:

```
somedef = get_option('somedef')
if somedef==4
  flags += ['-DSOMEDEF=4']

  # etc...
endif
```